# MySQL time type

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE blurt (blurtid integer,  btime datetime );
```

I did this query above and I got an error.
The reason is probably because "btime" from the data is something like 1/22/12. However, datetime is something like 1-22-2012.

Which type should btime be?
Thanks guys!

Comment: There's no query in your question. Did you forget the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following create table statement should not cause an error:

```
CREATE TABLE blurt (blurtid integer,  btime datetime );
```

But trying to insert `'1/22/12'` into a `datetime` column *will* cause error.  MySQL has a function called [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) which can help with that:

```
INSERT INTO blurt(1, STR_TO_DATE('1/22/12', '%m/%d/%y'))
```

If your dates had the format `'2012-01-22'` then you could insert them directly.  By the way, you are making the right decision by using a date type to store your date information.